# Can I use the Music Genome Project?

Tags: database, api, genome

Is there an API or database I can access or is it a proprietary project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Music Genome Project is owned by Pandora Media, Inc.  Unless you get into contact with them directly (and even if you ask nicely), I don't think you'll gain any access to it.

There is no Pandora API that currently exists, but I found something that might be helpful:

http://code.google.com/p/openpandora/

If you look into this, it should provide a little bit of insight into how to connect to pandora and use some of its services.

TlDr: No, not directly anyways.